# Oracle 11g-Could not open Connection using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, hibernate-mapping, spring-3, tiles2

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sttv.pngstrong text

Not able to open the connection for Oracle 11g using hibernate-I also verified the service and hostname in the file "tnsnames.ora"

Comment: Hibernate File--->  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" /> <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl" />
<property name="user" value="admin" />
<property name="password" value="admin" />
<property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
  <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
  <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
  <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />
 </bean>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check if you are providing right user name and password

Comment: Thanks that solves my problem...I created a new user and grant the dba access and then tried it worked for me.